# MySQL Query To Retrieve Data With Column Names

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, sql

I am writing some tool which has to retrieve column names of the retrieved data set when any query is applied to it.

If you're familiar with phpMyAdmin, you would realize the SQL pane does what is it runs your query and shows result with the column names. I wonder how hard the query would be, it always results in column names and what's actually the programming behind the scene? Is it like, it analyzes the query and then find table names from it and then first retrieve column names using query `show columns from table-name` and then the data?

Is there any better way?

**UPDATED**
Sorry for incomplete information, I think I must say I am using MySQL connector for .NET and am using C#.

Comment: What language are you writing in? There probably is a pre-made way to retrieve query metadata.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your columns are part of the metadate of the DataReader or DataTable that you load in c#

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnname.aspx) for DataTable:

```
private void PrintColumnNames(DataSet dataSet)
{
    // For each DataTable, print the ColumnName.
    foreach(DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
    {
        foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName);
        }
    }
}
```

For a DataReader, see [Can you get the column names from a SqlDataReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681653/can-you-get-the-column-names-from-a-sqldatareader)

Comment: I will mark your solution as answer because you got more votes than my own solution :)

Answer (score 6):

I resolved my issue using following code.

```
var QueryCommand = new MySqlCommand(txtQuery.Text, Connection);
var ResultReader = QueryCommand.ExecuteReader();

for (var f = 0; f < ResultReader.FieldCount; f++)
{
   ResultGrid.Columns.Add("column" + f, ResultReader.GetName(f));
}
```

Comment: Which is similar to my answer which is for c#. Is there a ResultReader in c# natively?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `SHOW COLUMNS`

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM City;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name       | char(35) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Country    | char(3)  | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| District   | char(20) | YES  | MUL |         |                |
| Population | int(11)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

But INFORMATION_SCHEMA is the ANSI means of determining columns, tables, constraints, etc.  [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/columns-table.html) is equivalent to `SHOW COLUMNS`:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
  [AND table_schema = 'db_name']
  [AND column_name LIKE 'wild']
```

Comment: The need is to get them with data itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need a programing language to do same as phpMyAdmin. You can use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

It will return a row of data in which each of the elements will have for key the name of the column:

PHP solution

```
array(
  [0] => array(
    [id] => 1,
    [name] => 'Test name'
  ),
  [1] => array(
    [id] => 2,
    [name] => 'Name 2'
  )
)
```

Comment: I am using C# and MySql .NET Connector

Comment: You hadn't specified any language in your question.

Comment: You solution is no doubt helpful from PHP perspective as I didn't realize this either.

Answer (score 0):

if you have determinated column count you can do it in pure mysql. For example for 3 column:

```
(select 
max(f1), max(f2), max(f3)
from (
select 
IF(ordinal_position=1,column_name,0) AS f1,
IF(ordinal_position=2,column_name,0) AS f2,
IF(ordinal_position=3,column_name,0) AS f3
from information_schema.columns where table_name='t') tt)
union
(select * from `t`)
```