# Retrieve Datareader using Objects

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqldatareader, cubes, adomd.net

I have worked on retrieving the data from SQL database using Datareader and populate it in Datatable.. But, I am wondering whether is there any way to handle the data from datareader **without using datatable ?**  I mean- handling the table values using **Objects should be more preferable..**

But, I dont want to use LINQ here since, I am going to use ADOMD object to pull the data from database(Cubes)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [dapper-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). I'm not sure how it works with ADOMD.NET, but it does neatly materialise query results in dynamic objects.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop thrugh the items and set it as the property values of your custom class. The below example read data from Customer table and Create a List of Customer Class object. Assuming you have a Customer POCO with ID and Name as Properties

```
List<Customer> custList= new List<Customer>();
string connString="yourConnectionStringHere";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID,NAME From Customer";           

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
           if (reader.HasRows)
           {  
             while (reader.Read())
             {
               var cust= new Customer();

                    if (!reader.IsDBNull( reader.GetOrdinal("ID")))
                        cust.ID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ID"));

                    if (!reader.IsDBNull( reader.GetOrdinal("Name")))
                        cust.Name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name"));

                    custList.Add(cust);
             }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public List GetEmployee(string spname)
        {

```
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = spname;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<EmployeeDetails> lstemp = new List<EmployeeDetails>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            EmployeeDetails emp = new EmployeeDetails();
            emp.EmployeeId =Convert.ToInt32( reader["EmployeeId"].ToString());
            emp.FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
            emp.LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
            emp.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DOB"].ToString());
            emp.Gender = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Gender"].ToString());
            emp.QName = reader["QName"].ToString();
            emp.Dname = reader["DName"].ToString();
            emp.Email = reader["Email"].ToString();



            lstemp.Add(emp);

        }


        return lstemp;
    }
```