# How to retrieve a particular value of a column based on another column of a same row?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I an reading data from a database table. Now I want to store the data in a variable. I need to put conditions depending on the values contained in the columns.

```
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select user_name,parameter_name,parameter_value from table1 where user_name ='USER'", ocConnection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if (dr["PARAMETER_NAME"].ToString() =="NAME1")
                {
                    class1.Value1 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PARAMETER_VALUE"].ToString());

                }

                if ((dr["PARAMETER_NAME"].ToString()) == "NAME2")
                {
                    class1.Value2 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PARAMETER_VALUE"].ToString());
                }
 dr.close();
 dr.Dispose();
}
```

But this gives an error as the control doesn't go inside any of the if blocks. 
Also gives an error such as :

> `System.IndexOutofRangeException` unable to find specified column in
>   resultset.

Though the values are there in the table.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes you can add the following line after you create the reader to get the names of the fields, which will be returned (statement taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/681671/1384848)):

```
var columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToList();
```

So you can check if `PARAMETER_NAME` and `PARAMETER_VALUE` will be returned as expected. Then you can further investigate your problem.

**Note:**

I recommend using the `using`-Statement for the `OracleCommand` and the `OracleDataReader`, so you don't have to call `Dispose` explicitly. Also, calling `dr.Close()` and `dr.Dispose()` does the same thing is not needed when using the `using`-Block. You also forgot to dispose the `OracleCommand`. With the second `using`-Block this is also fixed.

```
using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select user_name,parameter_name,parameter_value from table1 where user_name ='USER'", ocConnection))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    using(OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // check column names for debugging purposes
        var columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToList();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (dr["PARAMETER_NAME"].ToString() =="NAME1")
            {
                class1.Value1 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PARAMETER_VALUE"].ToString());
            }

            if ((dr["PARAMETER_NAME"].ToString()) == "NAME2")
            {
                class1.Value2 = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PARAMETER_VALUE"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```