# How can i get schema table for MySql query using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

my code is like this,

but i cannot find data types like int, varchar  for particular columns.

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString)
con.Open();

var QueryCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select * from Customers", con);
var ResultReader = QueryCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);

var dt = ResultReader.GetSchemaTable();
```

Comment: this will be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681653/can-you-get-the-column-names-from-a-sqldatareader

Comment: ya thanx seems like i can get more idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
DESCRIBE [databasename].[tablename];
```

or,

```
SHOW [databasename].[tablename];
```