# Print all the columns of a DB table, without writing each column name in the print statement

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, console

I have a table of students in SQL Server and I want to execute a query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_students;
```

but I don't want to write each column number getValue(0) getValue(1) in C# to get the result,

I wrote in the following statement

```
Console.WriteLine("{0},\t{1}", sqlDReader.GetValue(0), sqlDReader.GetValue(1));
```

I just want to get all the column values without writing each column index number, can't we simply get a string of the complete record, preferably with spaces of tabs in between?

Comment: `can't we simply get a string of a complete record` you could write a mehtod to do just that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681653/can-you-get-the-column-names-from-a-sqldatareader check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can.  Assuming you are using c#, something like this would work

If you know the number of columns:

```
string completeLine = "";
for(int i = 0 ; i < numCols ; i++)
{
    completeLine += sqlDReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
    if (i < numCols - 1)
        completeLine += " ";
}
Console.WriteLine (completeLine);
```

This assumes all columns can be cast to a string.  Also assumes you know number of columns.  There's a bunch of more complex ways to do this.

To get number of rols you can get the .Columns.Count or similar.

Then have an outer loop, for each row.  Note: do not try to do this type of string concatenation on the entire table as it will be slow (since string are really not changeable).