# Is there a way to fill combobox with column names from certain table?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a table where I'm saving payments each user made for each month and originally I had column named month but after saving couple of payments for every month it would become too clustered so I decided to ditch column month and add 12 columns named (january, february, etc. all the way to december) and now I want to display all 12 columns in combobox so I can select January and make payment for that month.

```
void FillCombo()
    {
        string constring = "server=localhost;user id=David;password=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=bazakudsumari";
        string Query = "SELECT * FROM bazakudsumari.evidencija_clanarina;";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            myReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string sSijecanj = myReader.GetString("sijecanj");
                odaberi_mjesec.Items.Add(sSijecanj);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Any way of doing this?

Comment: @Eric Yes, but I'm not trying to add values from columns, I need to fill combobox with column names (January, February, etc. all the way to December) and then when I select let's say January and make payment that it inserts data only in that column, January. If you can get what I'm asking. :)

Comment: The month's names are well known, why do you want to do this task reading a database table schema instead of adding directly the month's names?

Comment: @Steve Well, because when displaying all users who payed couple of months in a datagridview then the data is clustered as hell, hard to read and find what you want. So this would be a cleaner solution, at least in my opinion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681653/can-you-get-the-column-names-from-a-sqldatareader Maybe this will help for getting the column names?

Comment: It is a lot more complicated. However if you want to do so take a look at the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html)

Comment: Okay, so I wrote the code like this 
public void FillComboBox() 
{
odaberi_mjesec.Items.Add("January").ToString();
} 

and it displays it how I wanted.

Comment: _odaberi_mjesec.Items.AddRange(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames);_

Comment: @Steve Oh, I like your solution even more. Any way to make first letter capital?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add the months names reading them directly from your CultureInfo

```
var months = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
                        .DateTimeFormat.MonthNames.Select(x =>  
             CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(x)).ToArray();
odaberi_mjesec.Items.AddRange(months);
```

Comment: I've upvoted your answer but since I have less than 15 reputation it won't be visible publicly. Thank you so much! Exactly what I wanted and needed.

Comment: Completely overlooked and forgot to check your solution as an answer. Fixed it. :)