# how to check if a datareader is null or empty

Tags: c#, null, sqldatareader

I have a datareader that return a lsit of records from a sql server database. I have a field in the database called "Additional". This field is 50% of the time empty or null.

I am trying to write code that checks if this field isnull. The logic behind this is:
If the field "Additional" contains text then display the info otherwise hide the field.

I have tried:

```
if (myReader["Additional"] != null)
{
    ltlAdditional.Text = "contains data";
}
else
{
     ltlAdditional.Text = "is null";
}
```

The above code gives me this error:

Exception Details: **System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Additional**

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

---

#### See Also:

> [Check for column name in a SqlDataReader object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373230/check-for-column-name-in-a-sqldatareader-object)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
if (myReader["Additional"] != DBNull.Value)
{
    ltlAdditional.Text = "contains data";
}
else
{
     ltlAdditional.Text = "is null";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Robert,
I tried your suggested code however it still gives me "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Additional" because in this case "Additional" is null

Comment: Although this is an older post, in VB  "If reader("Additional") <> System.DBNull.Value Then"    this code returns the error "Operator '<>' is not defined for types 'Object' and 'System.DBNull'

Comment: In VB the syntax is "If Not reader("Additional") Is DBNull.Value Then"

Answer (score 16):

```
if (myReader.HasRows) //The key Word is **.HasRows**

{

    ltlAdditional.Text = "Contains data";

}

else

{   

    ltlAdditional.Text = "Is null Or Empty";

}
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me but in Windows Phone 8.1 it shuld be myReader.HasRows, without "()".

Comment: This answers my question and the question in the title, but the original post suggests that the title is totally wrong. Glad its here for people looking for an answer to the title question. Just sad its so far down...

Comment: I'm not sure this is valid for the circumstance.  Unless the query fails to execute, the SqlReader will ALWAYS have at least one empty dataset row.

Answer (score 11):

I haven't used DataReaders for 3+ years, so I wanted to confirm my memory and found this.  Anyway, for anyone who happens upon this post like I did and wants a method to test IsDBNull using the column name instead of ordinal number, and you are using VS 2008+ (& .NET 3.5 I think), you can write an extension method so that you can pass the column name in:

```
public static class DataReaderExtensions
{
    public static bool IsDBNull( this IDataReader dataReader, string columnName )
    {
        return dataReader[columnName] == DBNull.Value;
    }
}
```

Kevin

Answer (score 8):

This is the correct and tested solution

```
if (myReader.Read())
{

    ltlAdditional.Text = "Contains data";
}
else
{   
    ltlAdditional.Text = "Is null";
}
```

Comment: what if their if `NULL` in particular column..?

Comment: Calling .Read() reads in the first row, so if DataReader is passed into a method / function with while(DataReader.Read()), would the first row then be skipped? If it does, I suppose we could use a do while.

Comment: This will only test if the DataReader has rows. The question was how to test for NULL values in specific fields. IDataReader docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8):

I also use OleDbDataReader.IsDBNull()

```
if ( myReader.IsDBNull(colNum) ) { retrievedValue = ""; }
else { retrievedValue = myReader.GetString(colNum); }
```

Comment: Shorthand: `retrievedValue = myReader.IsDBNull(colNum) ? string.Empty : myReader.GetString(colNum);` Note that colNum can be swapped for colName.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you probably want to check for a `DBNull` not a regular `Null`.

Or you could look at the `IsDBNull` method

Comment: In this database table there are 15 rows. 14 of them return data however the 15th ("Additional") doesn;t always contain data. How would .HasRows work with the valid rows?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestions given, you can do this directly from your query like this -

```
SELECT ISNULL([Additional], -1) AS [Additional]
```

This way you can write the condition to check whether the field value is < 0 or >= 0.

Comment: I usually follow this pattern since NULL represents nothing in a DB.

Answer (score 1):

@Joe Philllips

SQlDataReader.IsDBNull(int index) requires the ordinal number of the column. Is there a way to check for nulls using Column Name, and not it's Ordinal Number?

Comment: i guess I could use 

    if (readerObject["ColumnName"] != DBNull.Value)

if I wanted to use column name instead of the ordinal number. Although I am not sure if there is a performance improvement (or degradation) between this approach and  the IsDBNull(columnOrdinalNumber) approach.

-Shiva
http://mycodetrip.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this simpler equivalent syntax:

```
ltlAdditional.Text = (myReader["Additional"] == DBNull.Value) ? "is null" : "contains data";
```

Answer (score 0):

I also experiencing this kind of problem but mine, i'm using DbDataReader as my generic reader (for SQL, Oracle, OleDb, etc.). If using DataTable, DataTable has this method:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Rows[0].Table.Columns.Contains("SampleColumn");
```

using this I can determine if that column is existing in the result set that my query has. I'm also looking if DbDataReader has this capability.

Answer (score 0):

This

Example:

```
objCar.StrDescription = (objSqlDataReader["fieldDescription"].GetType() != typeof(DBNull)) ? (String)objSqlDataReader["fieldDescription"] : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to get this done in query. However, if query bond to other functions than checking DBNull.Value in while loop would address the issue.

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
   while (reader.Read())
   {
      (reader["Additional"] != DBNull.Value) ? "contains data" : "is null";
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

AMG - Sorry all, was having a blond moment. The field "Additional" was added to the database after I had initially designed the database.

I updated all my code to use this new field, however I forgot to update the actual datareader code that was making the call to select the database fields, therefore it wasn't calling "Additional"