# SQLDataReader issue with reading null values

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

I am having problem with SQLDataReader when it comes into situation that I have one row of data, and one or tho columns (fields) have null value.

Can anybody help with this? Null values are related to string, float and datetime datatype.

First method is:

```
public class SpajanjeCollection:ObservableCollection<Spajanje>
{
    public static SpajanjeCollection GetAllSpajanjes() 
    {
        SpajanjeCollection spajanjes = new SpajanjeCollection();  
        Spajanje spajanje = null;  

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())  
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ToString();    
            conn.Open();    

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Ponude.IdPonude, Ponude.SifraProizvoda, Proizvodi.Naziv, Proizvodi.Opis, Proizvodi.PocetnaCijena, Ponude.PocetakAukcije, Users.UserName, Ponude.PonudjenaCijena, Ponude.ZavrsetakAukcije, Ponude.Status FROM  Ponude LEFT OUTER JOIN Users ON Ponude.Kupac = Users.UserName INNER JOIN Proizvodi ON Ponude.SifraProizvoda = Proizvodi.Id", conn);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())   
                {
                    spajanje = Spajanje.GetSpajanjeFromResultSet(reader);
                    spajanjes.Add(spajanje);    
                }
            }
        }
        return spajanjes;   
    }
}
```

Second method for data reading is:

```
    public static Spajanje GetSpajanjeFromResultSet(SqlDataReader reader) 
    {
        Spajanje spajanje = new Spajanje(Convert.ToInt16(reader["IdPonude"]), Convert.ToInt16(reader["SifraProizvoda"]), Convert.ToString(reader["Naziv"]), Convert.ToString(reader["Opis"]), float.Parse(reader["PocetnaCijena"].ToString()), (DateTime?)reader["PocetakAukcije"], Convert.ToString(reader["UserName"]), float.Parse(reader["PonudjenaCijena"].ToString()), (DateTime?)reader["ZavrsetakAukcije"], Convert.ToString(reader["Status"]));

        return spajanje;    
    }
```

Comment: I can not read data from SQL Server table if it finds row in which some fields have null value

Comment: Still not good enough. What do you mean by "cannot read"? If you get an error, show the error. If you get unexpected results, explain what  they are and what you expect instead.

Comment: When I start program, I am getting error message "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'" on Second method. Is it more clear now. I have data in SQL table but some fields have null value and when I start program I get this message

Comment: It doesn't help much. I don't need to test if some rows have empty value, but I need to force SqlDataReader to properly read those rows without stacking application

Comment: Add a COALESCE around the column names in the DataReader query.

Comment: Please, can you use my code and show me exactly how should it look like. Thank you in advance, I am beginner in C# and SQL and I really need help

Comment: coalesce is not solution. I want that SQLDataReader read all values from row and if it finds some column null, replace it with "" of 0. I don't want to change array structure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check if a datareader is null or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762861/how-to-check-if-a-datareader-is-null-or-empty)