# If/Else in Inline Synatx to declase class object with properties C#

Tags: c#

I have requirement to dynamically add property values based on column values. Current I am creating object as below:

```
while (rd.Read())
 {
   list.Add(new DeviceModelInfo()
    {
       ID = rd.GetGuid("ID"),
       Manufacturer = new Manufacturer()
       {
         ID = rd.GetGuid("ManufacturerID"),
         Name = rd.GetString("ManufacturerName"),
         ManufacturerType (ManufacturerEnum)rd.GetInt32("ManufecturerType")
       },
       Model = rd.GetString("Model"),
       IMEI = rd.GetString("IMEI")
    });
 }
```

But I need to check if IMEI column is available or not in `DataReader` but when I am using if else then its giving syntax error I want to add IMEI if its available in `DataReader` how can I achieve that?

```
 if (rd.GetName(i).Equals("IMEI", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    IMEI = rd.GetString("IMEI")
```

Comment: what is the syntax error showing ?

Comment: Please indicate what is the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Where does `i` suddenly come from? Do you have a method of checking, if a specific column name exists? Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/813741/1336590

Comment: Does your `SELECT` query have IMEI column ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming `i` is already a variable somewhere which has the number of the column that will be the IMEI if it's available. If that's not the case, see the end of the answer.

You can't use an `if` statement in an object initializer. What you *could* do is separate it out into a separate statement:

```
while (rd.Read())
{
    var device = new DeviceModlInfo
    {
        ID = rd.GetGuid("ID"),
        Manufacturer = new Manufacturer()
        {
           ID = rd.GetGuid("ManufacturerID"),
           Name = rd.GetString("ManufacturerName"),
           ManufacturerType (ManufacturerEnum)rd.GetInt32("ManufecturerType")
        },
        Model = rd.GetString("Model");
    };
    if (rd.GetName(i).Equals("IMEI", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        device.IMEI = rd.GetString("IMEI");
    }
    list.Add(device);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the *conditional ?: operator* to assign one value or another to `IMEI` based on a condition:

```
while (rd.Read())
{
    list.Add(new DeviceModelInfo
    {
       ID = rd.GetGuid("ID"),
       Manufacturer = new Manufacturer()
       {
           ID = rd.GetGuid("ManufacturerID"),
           Name = rd.GetString("ManufacturerName"),
           ManufacturerType (ManufacturerEnum)rd.GetInt32("ManufecturerType")
       },
       Model = rd.GetString("Model"),
       IMEI = rd.GetName(i).Equals("IMEI", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            ? rd.GetString("IMEI") : null;
   });
```

}

---

If you actually don't know *which* column would be the IMEI, I'd probably write a separate method to check whether the column is present or not, just once. You'd then write (outside the loop):

```
int? imeiColumn = GetColumn(dr, "IMEI");
```

Then in your object initializer, write:

```
IMEI = imeiColumn != null ? dr.GetString(imeiColumn.Value) : null
```

Where `GetColumn` might look something like:

```
static int? GetColumn(DbDataReader reader, string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.VisibleFieldCount; i++)
    {
        if (reader.GetName(i).Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What is i variable ?

Comment: @GaurangDave: See my edit for both the case where it's known as the column that will contain the IMEI if it's present, or not (at the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension method:

```
public static bool ColumnExists(this IDataRecord dr, string ColumnName)
{
    for (int i=0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        if (dr.GetName(i).Equals(ColumnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Use:

```
while (rd.Read())
{
    if(rd.ColumnExists("IMEI"))
    // DO YOUR WORK
}
```

Another way using LINQ:

Only work with .NET 3.5 and above

```
 while (rd.Read())
 {
     if(Enumerable.Range(0, rd.FieldCount).Any(c => rd.GetName(c) == "IMEI"))
     // DO YOUR WORK
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional operator `?:` to check whether `IMEI` column exist or not. If Column exist then get the value otherwise set `IMEI` value as `No IMEI`( whatever you like)

So change,

```
IMEI = rd.GetString("IMEI") //Inside list.Add(new DeviceModelInfo()..)
```

to

```
IMEI = rd.GetName(i).Equals("IMEI", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? rd.GetString("IMEI"):"No IMEI"
```

Comment: Where the `i` comes from?

Comment: May be from outer loop, that is up to him as he gave condition as like that in if statement. This code will be helpful to him.