# Exception handling: user defined exception benefits

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, programming-languages, exception

My exception handling skills are very primary and I am always very confused about the way I should use them, not so much of the how/syntax. I am currently using C# (if there would be different things applicable to it).

My question is that what are the benefits of creating your own Exception class while developing an application? In comparison to throwing a standard Exception class exception. Basically what is a healthy practice of exceptions in your application.

Or if not benefits, then disadvantages?

Comment: I have voted up all the answers that were helpful to me and as there were so many (Thank you) that I found beneficial to me, I decided to vote instead of picking one answer.

Answer (score 5):

By creating your own exceptions you can often create a more meaningful message (or more application specific type of message) for the end user, while still wrapping the original message, so as not to lose any useful information.

There is a great [book by Bill Wagner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321245660) that covers some reasoning about when you should or should not create your own exceptions along with some good practices for exception handling in general. Here is a small excerpt:

> Your application will throw exceptions -- hopefully not often, but it
>   will happen. If you don't do anything specifc, your application will
>   generate the default .NET Framework exceptions whenever something goes
>   wrong in the methods you call on the core framework. Providing more
>   detailed information will go a long way to enabling you and your users
>   to diagnose and possibly correct errors in the field. You create
>   different exception classes when different corrective actions are
>   possible and only when different actions are possible. You create
>   full-featured exception classes by providing all the constructors that
>   the base exception class supports. You use the InnerException property
>   to carry along all the error information generated by lower-level
>   error conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the book reference!

Comment: @nEm: No problem. Great read. He also released another book called More Effective C#: 50 Specific Ways to Improve Your C#, which is just as good. http://www.amazon.com/More-Effective-Specific-Ways-Improve/dp/0321485890

Comment: Oh nice! Thanks a lot again. I'll check them out. Without healthy coding habits, knowledge of the language is of no use.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a specific type of problem unique to your application that will call for a unique recovery strategy at a higher level in your application, you should create your own exception type so you can recognize and recover from that sort of problem optimally.

If the error is more of a "the caller did something wrong" variety, use the standard exception classes.

If you think your library is going to be long-lived and valuable, I would err on the side of creating your own exception classes, so that future users of your library can fashion their own recovery strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you want to do diffrent things for diffrent types of error, for example if a user inputs bad data it dosent make sence to crash the whole application and email the administrator. It would make sence to do that for a more serious exeption such as a stack overflow. You would then impliment diffrent catches depending on the type of error.

Comment: Is that because throwing an `Exception' exception could be caught anywhere since it is generalised?

Comment: Bad user input should not raise an exception. Exceptions are for exceptional cases, while it is expected that users input bad data.

Comment: Sjoerd: Idealy yes but sometimes user inputs slip past your validation

Comment: oh I didnt mean to imply only for bad user input, I am speaking in the case of throwing an exception because I need to.

Comment: yes I do agree with Tom Squires, sometimes you may forget to check the boolean result of a validation method with no exceptions for user input

Comment: nEm: I personally like to have my own exceptions implimented that email me if an exception is thrown. That way i know the second something goes wrong. So ie if you cant connect to the datbase then it lets me know and raises a unique type of exception i can handle uniquely.

Answer (score 2):

If a method is documented as throwing some particular class of exception in some particular circumstance, it should ensure that there's no way any exception of the class can bubble up through it in other circumstances.  In many cases, the most practical way to ensure this may be to create a custom exception class.

Actually, I would regard much of the exception hierarchy as being pretty useless, and would suggest focusing on a fairly small number of exceptions, from which nearly all good exceptions should derive.

1. CleanFailureException -- The indicated operation could not be performed for some reason, but has not altered any object's state.  There is no reason to believe any object's state is corrupt except to the extent implied by the operation's failure.  This should be the type of exception thrown by a DoSomething method if a TrySomething method would return False.  May in some cases be wrapped in a more severe instruction, if a failed operation leaves one or more objects in partially-altered or inconsistent states.
2. StateDisturbedException -- The indicated operation could not be completely performed for some reason, but may have been partially performed.  The object on which an action was being performed has a state which complies with its own invariants, but may or may not comply with caller's expectations of it.  Caller may attempt to use the object only after examining it and making sure it complies with expectations (changing it as needed).  Alternatively, this exception should be caught at the point where the target object would no longer exist, and then wrapped in a CleanFailureException.
3. TargetStateCorruptException -- The indicated operation could not be performed because the particular object being acted upon is corrupt, but there is no particular reason to expect that corruption extends outside the object.  This exception should be caught at the point where the target object would no longer exist, and then wrapped and replaced with CleanFailureException.
4. ParentStateCorruptException -- The indicated operation could not be performed because some object which the target's documentation would regard as a "parent" object is corrupt.  Catch at the level where the corrupt parent objects would no longer exist, then wrap in a "CleanFailureException".
5. SystemOnFireException

While it may be nice to have exception names that indicate the nature of what went wrong, from a catching perspective what matters is whether one can safely catch and resume.  Any exception hierarchy should focus on the latter issues, rather than the former.  If the goal is to inform *people* of what went wrong, that should be done in Exception.Message.

Answer (score 1):

The main benefits are to add information, so exceptions are more meaningful and thus allowing to catch exceptions that are specific to your application.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing an exception is actually a more expensive operation than quietly failing, such as returning a bool. This question highlights what I mean:

[How much more expensive is an Exception than a return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282252/how-much-more-expensive-is-an-exception-than-a-return-value)

If you're writing something that you anticipate other developers are going to be using in their own project, then sure, an exception could be useful for them to make sure they're using your code right. Otherwise, if you're just using it within your own codebase, I would make sure to quietly fail.

Answer (score 1):

One example where custom exceptions work well is when you are expecting external applications to interface with your project.

For example, if you had a small project that sends out an email it might make sense to throw a custom 'TooFewRecipients' error if you had a hard limit on the minimum number of recipients that must be emailed.

Custom exceptions will in general inherit from System.Exception

Remember that Exceptions should only be used for exceptional cases which your project can't handle in any other way, and they should be understandable enough to aid a 3rd party developer understand the issue.  There is more information at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx)