# An approach for checking for new content and downloading it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a desktop client which checks for **new content** on the server via ASP.NET Web API and saves it locally. something like an email client.

But I don't know exactly what is the best way to implement this, I mean I should have a controller for checking if there is new content, and then client calls another controller for downloading it, or what?

any clues is appreciated.

Comment: What I do in you case it will be to add a header with the last update time, and read only that header from the desktop client - if found different then I go to download the new content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people use a polling approach, whereby the app passes in a date or identifier the last time the system checked for updates, then stream any new updates to the desktop client.  All you would need to do is call a method that checks the database for updates as of a specific time, stream the new ones, and then add the new ones to the result set (or refresh the entire results).

```
public class UpdatesController : ApiController
{
   public object Get(long millisecondsAsOf)
   {
     //Query from DB, return  results, or return true/false if there are new records.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The restful approach is described here [Returning http status code from Web Api controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655350/returning-http-status-code-from-asp-net-mvc-4-web-api-controller) you need to take the last updated time into your controller method, use this to check whether a change has been made sice that date, if it hasn't changed then return an HTTP status code of 304 Not Modified and omit the response; however, if it has changed send the resource as normal with a 200 OK.

Personally I would modify the approach mentioned above a bit by managing the last updated via the http headers and etag. That a read of this [here](http://www.rapidsnail.com/Tutorial/t/2012/108/2/1090/the-http-response-last-modified-and-etag-and-aspnet-web-api-realize.aspx) for more information.