# Return JSON file with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, javascript, json, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to return a JSON file using ASP.NET Web API (for testing).

```
public string[] Get()
{
    string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\data.json");

    return text;
}
```

In Fiddler this does appear as a Json type but when I debug in Chrome and view the object it appears as and array of individual lines (left). The right image is what the object should look like when I am using it.

**Can anyone tell me what I should return to achieve a Json result in the correct format?**

[image: alt]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome..May help you!

Comment: @ssilas777 I don't think that's the same question. That's about returning XML vs. JSON as opposed to returning incorrect JSON.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Does the file already has valid JSON in it? If so, instead of calling `File.ReadAllLines` you should call `File.ReadAllText` and get it as a single string. Then you need to parse it as JSON so that Web API can re-serialize it.

```
public object Get()
{
    string allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\data.json");

    object jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(allText);
    return jsonObject;
}
```

This will:

1. Read the file as a string
2. Parse it as a JSON object into a CLR object
3. Return it to Web API so that it can be formatted as JSON (or XML, or whatever)

Comment: how would one do this if the .JSON file would be an uri and not on c:, the file does not accept an uri as input

Answer (score 23):

I found another solution which works also if anyone was interested.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var stream = new FileStream(@"c:\data.json", FileMode.Open);

    var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The generic HttpResponseMessage is now deprecated as it wasn't Type <T> safe.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655350/returning-http-status-code-from-asp-net-mvc-4-web-api-controller

Comment: +1: The HttpResponseMessage may be deprecated, but it worked in the situation where the JSON property names were not valid CLR (e.g. had spaces in them). Your answer gave me the clue I needed to return generated raw text as JSON. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I needed something similar, but [IHttpActionResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758615/why-should-i-use-ihttpactionresult-instead-of-httpresponsemessage) ([WebApi2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)) was required.

```
public virtual IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    var result = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\temp\some.json"))
    };

    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    return ResponseMessage(result);
}
```