# Web Api Request.CreateResponse HttpResponseMessage no intellisense VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

For some reason, `Request.CreateResponse` is now "red" in VS2012 and when I hover over the usage the IDE says

> Cannot resolve symbol 'CreateResponse'

Here is the ApiController Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using GOCApi.Attributes;
using GOCApi.Models;
using GOCApi.Models.Abstract;
using AttributeRouting;
using AttributeRouting.Web.Http;

namespace GOCApi.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("Courses")]
    public class CoursesController : ApiController
    {
        private ICoursesRepository _coursesRepository { get; set; }

        public CoursesController(ICoursesRepository coursesRepository)
        {
            _coursesRepository = coursesRepository;
        }

        [GET("{id}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
        {
            var course = _coursesRepository.GetSingle(id);
            if (course == null)
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Invalid ID");
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, course);
        }
    }
}
```

Granted, the code does compile and works, it's just really annoying seeing all the "red" on my screen. Also, the intellisense doesn't work now when I type `Request.CreateResponse`. This also used to work, but I started developing other parts to my API and just came back to building controllers so I do not know what happened.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It happens a lot to me and the way it comes back is to close down VS and re-open it, annoyance that I have to live with, hope not for long.

Comment: @von v. I've tried that, no luck :/

Comment: Make sure the file build action property is set to "Compile" and not "Content".

Answer (score 22):

You need to add a reference to `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll`. The `CreateResponse` extension method is defined there.

Comment: iroel, it's probably because your controller is not deriving from ApiController.

Comment: You must reference the System.Net.Http.Formatting dll BUT the *using* is System.Net.Http. You need both.

Comment: Note that you will need a Using statement as well after adding the reference.  This solved my issue.

Answer (score 21):

Because this extension method lives in `System.Net.Http`, you just need to include it in your usings statements.

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

Comment: The OP did at line 5. Without it would not compile.

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
 HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Gone)
```

instead of

```
 Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone)
```

Comment: I think there's something wrong with this implementation. You are creating a response based on default values. Where here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh969014(v=vs.118).aspx it says the generated response from the request will  be created "wired up" to the request.. I have no idea what "wired up" means :)

Comment: Thanks! This helped me in a project where the implementation is not in a controller.

Answer (score 6):

This is because you have to do:

```
namespace GOCApi.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("Courses")]
    public class CoursesController : ApiController
    {
        private ICoursesRepository _coursesRepository { get; set; }

        public CoursesController(ICoursesRepository coursesRepository)
        {
            _coursesRepository = coursesRepository;
        }

        [GET("{id}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
        {
            var course = _coursesRepository.GetSingle(id);
            if (course == null){
               return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Invalid ID");
            }
            return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, course);
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `this`.
In my case the compiler now gets it.
Saw the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655350/returning-http-status-code-from-asp-net-mvc-4-web-api-controller#answer-11328266)

Comment: This is actually quite weird, once I put down `this` it said I could remove it...

Comment: Base class originally was `Controller` in my auto created solution, once I changed it to `ApiController` suddenly the `CreateResponse` was found.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to `System.Web.Http` to the project. Then add

```
Using System.Web
```

to the top of the cs file.

Answer (score -2):

This a known issue with VB.NET and Request.CreateResponse.

There is a workaround:
[Missing request.CreateResponse in vb.net Webapi Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509543/missing-request-createresponse-in-vb-net-webapi-projects/21164101#21164101)