# Return a String in Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

As simple as it sounds, I haven't found any documentation on this and perhaps I'm wording it wrong so if so, some good documentation on this would be appreciated. I simply want to return a string or a model of type string.

```
return "string here";
```

**I get this error every time:**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult'  TaskManagement  C:\dev\TaskManagement\TaskManagement\Controllers\JobsController.cs  157
```

**I've also tried using a CAST - same error.**

```
return (IHttpActionResult)"string"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can do this which returns a 200 (Ok) :

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok("some string");
}
```

Take a look at the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller_methods(v=vs.118).aspx) to see what else you can return ie: `ok`, `badrequest` etc

Comment: I knew it had to be that simple. As you can tell, I'm new to WebAPI. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, this is just one way of doing what you want, take a look here for some more methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816049/web-api-request-createresponse-httpresponsemessage-no-intellisense-vs2012

Answer (score 3):

As Ric mentioned Ok() will do it

```
return Ok("some string");
```

However, not all of the ApiController Methods will allow you to pass a string so if you don't want to return a Success status, you can use Content()

```
return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "string here");
```

You can also pass an object back with Content if you want:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var responseObject = responseGenerator.GetResponseForInvalidModelState(ModelState);
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, responseObject);
}
```