# JSON String gets cut off

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My application is an ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API.

If my Controller Returns a small JSON, everything works fine.
However, if the JSON gets bigger, I am getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPsyz.png)

Visual Studio is giving me this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSPOw.png)

This is the Controller and the Method that creates the Data (shortened)

```
  [HttpGet]
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserData()
  {        
        return this.Ok(GetSomeData());
  }

   private List<MyUser> GetSomeData()
   {
       var userList = new List<MyUser>();
       for (int i = 0; i < 2500; i++)
       {
            userList.Add(new MyUser{
                Name = "Data",
                Age = i,
                Phone = "000",
            });
       }
       return userList;
   }
```

If the loop is getting to big, Iam getting the errors listed above.

Keep in mind that the code is extremely simplified. But everything works fine, until to much data is returned.

I have tried to change the `maxJsonLength` in the `web.config` as it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config).

Comment: For whoever is interested, my question got answered in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42924571/microsoft-windowsazure-storage-storageexception-badrequest-strings-32768-azur) post.

Answer (score 0):

See, with web api and json there is a limit to the amount of data you can transfer. But a quirky way could be to return a text/plain data serialized as json.

So if you changed your `GetUserData()` action as such:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetUserData()
{     
   var result = GetSomeData();
   var response = Request.CreateResponse();
   response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
   return response;
}
```

And then in your client, you can construct your object back by using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
This doesnt work for me.. When i try to get the package "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core", Iam getting the error message that it's not compatble with "netcoreapp1.0".

Therefore I dont have the Method CreateResponse();

Do you have any other advices?

Comment: I found a workaround to get the Response object here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816049/web-api-request-createresponse-httpresponsemessage-no-intellisense-vs2012)  


I shall use HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Gone) instead of


Request.CreateResponse()     

But this doesnt work for me..

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had a middleware that throw exception and closed response too soon