# Azure Storage exception when a string length is more than 32768 characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-table-storage

My application is an ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API. If my controller returns a small string, everything works fine. But if the string length gets longer than 32768, i'm getting the following error message:

```
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Htpp.Frame`1.<RequestProcessAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
Request Information
RequestID:440ed7db-0002-006f-742e-a28f82000000
RequestDate:Tue, 21 Mar 2017 11:30:40 GMT
StatusMessage:Bad Request
ErrorCode:PropertyValueTooLarge
```

This is my Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("plain/text")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetData()
{
    return this.Ok(this.GetResponse());
}

private string GetResponse()
{
    string retVal = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32769; i++)
    {
        retVal = retVal + "a";
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

The full error message:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: BadRequest
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.<ExecuteAsyncInternal>d__4`1.MoveNext() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Windows Runtime\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 315
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MyProjectNameLogging.AzureStorageLoggingConnector.<WriteToRequestLogAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in AzureStorageLoggingTable.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at MyProjectNameLogging.Repositories.RequestLoggingRepository.<WriteToLogAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in Repositories\RequestLoggingRepository.cs:line 36
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at MyProjectNameLogging.Middleware.RequestMiddleware.<Invoke>d__2.MoveNext() in Middleware\RequestMiddleware.cs:line 69
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi.Application.SwaggerUiMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi.Application.RedirectMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Swashbuckle.Swagger.Application.SwaggerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware.<Invoke>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Hosting.Internal.RequestServiceContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompillerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Htpp.Frame`1.<RequestProcessAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
Request Information
RequestID:6d8afaf4-0002-00cd-1235-a2421e000000
RequestDate:Tue, 21 Mar 2017 12:24:57 GMT
StatusMessage:Bad Request
ErrorCode:PropertyValueTooLarge
```

I would like to return strings way longer than 32768.

Any advices?

Comment: Although it wouldn't help you, others may benefit if that error message was in text rather than as an image, as it would appear when they search for the same problem. Might even result in a few upvotes for you and anyone answering!

Comment: what is `Ok()`?

Comment: @JuryGolubev its a Method from abstract class ControllerBase

Comment: Could you show us the full error message of the exception?

Comment: @bl4y I added them :)

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt Just FYI, I've just run the same code, both as-is and changing it from `"a"` to `"aa"`, and it worked both times. I'm running within Docker; I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: It looks like you're tripping over something related to Azure, so may be worthwhile tagging that specifically. That error (`PropertyValueTooLarge`) brings up lots of Azure-related content, and your filenames also mention Azure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are encountered the Azure Storage limit for the string property type ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/Understanding-the-Table-Service-Data-Model)):

> Edm.String (String) - A UTF-16-encoded value. String values may be up to 64 KB in size.

Because UTF-16 encoded strings require 2 bytes to store an character the maximum string length is 32768 characters.

Comment: It turned out that I tried to log the which im responding to azure , which isnt possible because of the 64KB limit.

thanks again you saved me many hours..

Comment: To log data use BLOB storage. [Azure Storage Services (Blob Service)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/azure-storage-services-rest-api-reference)

Comment: It turned out that I tried to log the data which im responding , which isnt possible because of the 64KB limit.

thanks again you saved me many hours..

Comment: is there any reason for this only happening sometimes? 

I tried this out a couple times with the same data (Size about 200Kb in strings) and sometimes it threw an exception, sometimes it worked.. Any idea?

Comment: @Moritz, I don't know. Ask that question to the Azure support. They should know how their code works.

Answer (score 2):

Though this has already been answered, I'd like to propose solution for anyone else who might come across this thread. I needed to store significantly more than 64k in a single property in my table entity. I found several references online to Lokad Fat Entities, however, it seems it is no longer actively supported and I had runtime errors with the version available on NuGet.org. So, here is a class that is inspired by Lokad's solution. I hope others find it useful.

```
    public class ExtEntity<T> : TableEntity where T : new()
{
    private const int MAX_BYTES_PER_ARR = 65500; // don't use full 64k to avoid any weird edge case

    // Serialized in DB and deserialized for callers
    public Byte[] A0 { get; set; }
    public Byte[] A1 { get; set; }
    public Byte[] A2 { get; set; }
    public Byte[] A3 { get; set; }
    public Byte[] A4 { get; set; }
    public Byte[] A5 { get; set; }
    public Byte[] A6 { get; set; }
    public Byte[] A7 { get; set; }
    public Byte[] A8 { get; set; }
    public Byte[] A9 { get; set; }
    public Byte[] A10 { get; set; }
    public Byte[] A11 { get; set; }
    public Byte[] A12 { get; set; }
    public Byte[] A13 { get; set; }
    public Byte[] A14 { get; set; }
    public Byte[] A15 { get; set; }
    private T value;

    public T Value
    {
        // Accessors automatically serialize and deserialize T value
        get
        {
            // ASSUMES that value will never change after first time deserialized!
            if (this.value == null)
            {
                int n = 0;
                using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        string propName = "A" + n++;
                        PropertyInfo prop = this.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
                        byte[] arr = (byte[])prop.GetValue(this);
                        if (arr == null || arr.Length == 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        memStream.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
                    }
                    memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    var binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
                    this.value = (T)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
                }
            }
            return this.value;
        }
        set
        {
            // First, ensure the type is serializable.
            if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable && !(typeof(ISerializable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("ExtEntity<T>.get_Value Exception: A serializable Type is required.");

            // Assign the value
            this.value = value;

            // Then searialize it for Table Storage use
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Serialize into memory stream, then seek back to origin
                bf.Serialize(memStream, this.value);
                memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                // Chunk data from memory stream into stored properties
                int bytesRemaining = (int)memStream.Length;
                int n = 0;
                while (bytesRemaining > 0)
                {
                    if (n > 15)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException("ExtEntity<T>.set_Value Exception: Data is too large.");
                    }
                    int numToRead = Math.Min(bytesRemaining, ExtEntity<T>.MAX_BYTES_PER_ARR);
                    byte[] arr = new byte[numToRead];
                    int numRead = memStream.Read(arr, 0, numToRead);
                    if (numRead != numToRead)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException("ExtEntity<T>.set_Value Exception: Unexpected number of bytes returned.");
                    }

                    string propName = "A" + n++;
                    PropertyInfo prop = this.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
                    prop.SetValue(this, arr);
                    bytesRemaining -= numRead;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
public class RawDataBlockEntity : ExtEntity<RawDataBlock>
{
    public RawDataBlockEntity(string rawDataId, string blockId, RawDataBlock block)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = rawDataId;
        this.RowKey = blockId;

        this.Value = block;
    }

    public RawDataBlockEntity() { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return new ContentResult { Content = this.GetResponse(), StatusCode = 200 };
```

Comment: Any explanation?