# Returning an IHttpActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following code below.

```
public IHttpActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginVM login)
{
    bool isAuthenticated = EmployeeSecurity.Login(login.quad, login.password);
    if (isAuthenticated)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Authorized"); 
        response.Headers.Add("Token", "test");
        response.Headers.Add("TokenExpiry", "testdate");
        response.Headers.Add("Role", "testrol");
        response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Token,TokenExpiry");
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
    }
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Please check your QUAD or password.");
}
```

I have the following error

> "Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on
>   'System.Web.HttpInputStream'.",

I do have the codes below in global.aspx.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
                .ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
                .Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Other API endpoints work correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I am not familiar with this API, but from sample code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816049/ you should `return response;`

Comment: @devio response works but i wanted to return IHttpActionResult. Guess I will stick to response.

Comment: It may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results

Comment: @AatishKumar *why* do you want to return an IHttpActionResult instead of an `IActionResult` like all Web API methods do? After all, your method returns only a status code with a description, not even an actual content

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static class HttpActionResultExtentions
{
    public static IHttpActionResult AddHeader(this IHttpActionResult result, string name, IEnumerable<string> values)
        => new HeaderActionResult(result, name, values);
private class HeaderActionResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        private readonly IHttpActionResult actionResult;

        private readonly Tuple<string, IEnumerable<string>> header;

        public HeaderActionResult(IHttpActionResult actionResult, string headerName, IEnumerable<string> headerValues)
        {
            this.actionResult = actionResult;

            header = Tuple.Create(headerName, headerValues);
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var response = await actionResult.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);

            response.Headers.Add(header.Item1, header.Item2);

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

I Get this form https://gist.github.com/testfirstcoder/90e6f09c4f40b36c2dd1

Comment: Code only answers are *not* considered good asnwers. You should explain how this code answers the original question, if at all. The OP didn't ask how to add headers to the response