# ASP.NET : Raising a 500 via 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult'.?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I'm sure this is simple but ... how are you meant to raise a HTTP 500 within a web service which returns a `IHttpActionResult`.

I can return a `System.Web.Http.Results.Ok` and end up with 200 client side but I can't find how to return anything other than a 200.

I've tried

```
   HttpStatusCodeResult r = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "BOO");
```

which is the right idea but I can't work out how to cast a `HttpStatusCodeResult` to `IHttpStatusCodeResult`.

I've also tried changing the return type to `HttpStatusCodeResult` (so I can use the above) but when I do that the jQuery on the client sees the result as a 'success' (even though with the Javascript you can see 'StatusCode' as 500 and the 'StatusDescription' as 'BOO'.

All I really want to do is :

- be free to return any HTTP return value
- include a message with it
- have jQuery recognise that some HTTP returns should be handled by .done and others by .fail

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK well I believe I have found a way to do this. The answer is in this SO question here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11328266 .

First you change the method return to `HttpResponseMessage`  .

Then when you wish to signal an error you execute :

```
return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "BIG PROBLEM");
```

Back on the client I have code which looks like this :

```
promise.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(".done for within updateButtonClickHandler");
            })
promise.fail(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(".fail for within updateButtonClickHandler");
            })
promise.always(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(".always for within updateButtonClickHandler");
```

And the result of executing `CreateErrorResponse` is that the `promise.fail` executes in the client-side code.

Within that javascript function `data.responseJSON.Message` holds the message passed as the second argument in the C# code (in my example "BIG PROBLEM") and data.status holds 500 (corresponding to the `HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError`).

You can adapt this to generate any HTTP code you wish to return by using different HttpResponseMessage values (of which there are quite a few).