# Get the StatusCode from a webapi with another parameter

Tags: angular

I would like to get the status code from a web api with this code:

**webapi**

```
public HttpResponseMessage AddPerson(Person person)
{
    var httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();

    var p = new Person();
    using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        p = person;
        try
        {
            var context = db.Database.BeginTransaction();
            p.DatOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(person.DatOfBirth);
            db.Persons.Add(p);
            db.SaveChanges();

            context.Commit();
            httpResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            httpResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable;
            httpResponse.ReasonPhrase = "Error in saving to database: " + ex.Message;
            return Request.CreateResponse(httpResponse);
        }
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(httpResponse.StatusCode, p);
}
```

** client **

```
addPerson() {
    this.clientService.addPerson(this.createClientForm.value)
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log(data.status);
    debugger;
    if (data.StatusCode === 200) {
        this.showSnackbar('Successfully added client');
        this.resetForms();
    }
    });
}
```

I can get the properties of the person but I cannot get the StatusCode. Can you help please. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried logging your response using console.log(data)? Does the status code appear there?

Comment: It does not appear. That's what puzzles me. How can I make it appear so I can call it.

Comment: The problem can be with your API, try sending status code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10658604/9766215)

Answer (score 0):

User status, it must have some code

```
 if (data.status=== 200) {
    this.showSnackbar('Successfully added client');
    this.resetForms();
}
```