# In HttpStatusCode I get a status 500 again when I change it to 401

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, http

I have a function that catches errors
And when an error occurs I check if it is an AJAX error
And if this AJAX changes the status of the error to 401 Unauthorized
I changed both the Result and the status Code
like this:

```
     filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
     filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
     filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
```

When I debug in c# I really see them 401 as what I changed and then it goes back to JS and there is 500 inside
does anyone know why?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655350/returning-http-status-code-from-web-api-controller
This may help you

Comment: My function is void and it does not return HttpResponseMessage I need to fill FilterContext with data

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was able to solve the problem

I should have simply added this sentence:

```
filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
```

Thanks

And good luck to everyone

Answer (score 0):

You should be throwing a HttpResponseException from your API method, not HttpException:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

Comment: I did what you said and he throws me an error :"System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException: 'Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.'"