# Controller calls web api, how to handle http error codes returned from API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Forgive me for my ignorance, I am new to writing and consuming ASP.Net Core web APIs.

I have a web project that has an MVC architecture. The controllers call a web api to get data.

This is what I have so far:

```
using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{_apiSettings.Value.BaseURL}/authors/{id}"))
{
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var authorData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AuthorDTO>(apiResponse);
        authorForm = _mapper.Map<AuthorViewModel>(authorData);
    }
    else
    {
        // What do I do here?
    }
}

// more stuff down here to get to view...
```

As you can see I am not sure what should happen when I don't get a 200 code from the API call.

[Edit]

Is there a way to pass on the same HTTP response code? Is this a bad idea because that info shouldn't get to the user?

Is it best to just throw an error? If so should it always just be an Internal Server error?

I am just looking for advice on best practices, I realize there is no *one* right answer here.

Comment: You could throw an exception, and let your global error handling catch it. Or you could display a different view with a suitable error message. *(Eg: `404` returns an "Author not found" view.)* There's no one right answer to this.

Comment: @RichardDeeming I figured there was no right answer, I will add some to my question to be more specific

Comment: I think you can log the time, url, status code, response content and other info can help you.

Comment: @player2135 That sounds like a great option, could you put that in an answer showing how to do so with a small example?

Comment: There are many ways to pass HTTP response status, you can refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655350/returning-http-status-code-from-web-api-controller

Answer (score 2):

I think you can log the time, url, status code, response content and other info can help you.
A Example From My Project

```
private static async Task<T> HandleHttpResponse<T>(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonHelper.ToObject<T>(HandleHttpResult(result));
    }
    else
    {
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        LogHelper.WriteLog($"请求{response.RequestMessage.RequestUri}错误，错误描述：{response.StatusCode}，错误码：{response.StatusCode.ToInt32()}，错误内容：{result}", $"{nameof(RemoteServerHelper)}_{nameof(HandleHttpResponse)}", true);
    }
    return default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several ways to return a request.

Example:

- System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Ok() (return status 200)
- System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest() (return status 400)

Here is the microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode?view=net-6.0