# Return CreateErrorResponse or throw new HttpResponseException

Tags: angularjs, exception, httpresponse, asp.net-web-api

I am new to Web API's (using C# in VS 2012) and attempting to help on a project that involves returning more meaningful errors to an AngularJS front-end, but I am not sure if there is a preferred method in regards to simply catching an error and saying

`return  Request.CreateErrorResponse(..`

versus

`throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(...`

I do not fully understand the pro's and con's or uses for returning a response error.

For more background, what happens is we are uploading Excel files and we have a variety of use cases that cause errors when parsing and such. I would like to asynchronously return error messages that give some clarity as to what is causing the error rather than an ambiguous "Exception".

So I am trying to something such as

```
try 
{
//stuff
}
catch (FormatException e)
{
   return  Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "issue 1");
}
catch (FileFormatException e)
{
   return  Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "issue 2");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   return  Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "issue 3");
}
```

Where I can give errors more purposeful meanings. I am just confused on whether I should just be "returning" a `Request.CreateErrorResponse`, or "throwing" an exception like `throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(...`

On the front-end I am just reading that error back

```
.error(function (data) {
        $scope.uploadFailed = true;     //shows the message span
        $scope.uploadMsg = data["Message"].trim();
 });
```

Forgive me if this is confusing, I am just trying to determine which way of returning errors would be best for this scenario and why.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one as answered this to-date... essentially you were asking, 
[How much more expensive is an Exception than a return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282252/how-much-more-expensive-is-an-exception-than-a-return-value)

From a performance point of view you are better to return an error response.

Generally I would recommend avoid throwing exceptions where possible, and especially if you expect them. Exceptions should be for exceptional cases.

As a rule of thumb I would say if you using client errors (4XX) they are not exceptional because you predicted them, for example when it is appropriate you can `TryParse` then return a 400 `BadRequest`.

Conversely if you are many layers deep into your application and a bad argument arrives where you are not expecting it, you could throw an exception and in these cases you might catch and wrap it in a 500 error response. Unlike the 4XX, you would have an `InternalServerError` because you were not expecting it.